# convertir a double siempre aparecen comas

Tags: vb.net

el codigo es para incluir en una tabla los registros de una compra, aunque convierto los valores en double con punto al convertirlos para la consulta se cambia el punto por una coma quedando asi
INSERT INTO compras1 (nrocompra, proveedor, nrofactura, tasa, fechacompra, subtotal, iva, totalc) VALUES ('2','provve','1212',28,2023/07/28,8064, 1290,24, 9354,24)
por eso me da error cuando intento colocarlos en la tabla
la tabla es de una base de datos de sqlite, lo que deseo es que no se convierta en cma el punto cuando pasa por la linea que convierte el insert en string

```
        Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Data.SQLite
Imports System.Reflection.Emit
Imports System.Text.Json
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Status

Public Class Compras2
    Public cbodes, cbomar, cboprese As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Public cot As Int64
    Public suma, iva, total As Double
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dispose()
        cerrar()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Compras_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        nrocont()
        DateTimePicker1.Value = Date.Now.ToShortDateString

        Dataco.ColumnCount = 8
        Dataco.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12)
        Dataco.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        Dataco.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue
        Dataco.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Descripcion"
        Dataco.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Marca"
        Dataco.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Presentacion"
        Dataco.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Cantidad"
        Dataco.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Precio Bs"
        Dataco.Columns(5).HeaderText = "Precio $"
        Dataco.Columns(6).HeaderText = "Total"
        Dataco.Columns(7).HeaderText = "Precio Venta"
        llenacombo()
        Dataco.Columns(0).Width = 400
        Dataco.Columns(1).Width = 120
        Dataco.Columns(2).Width = 120
        Dataco.Columns(3).Width = 120
        Dataco.Columns(4).Width = 120
        Dataco.Columns(5).Width = 120
        Dataco.Columns(6).Width = 120
        Dataco.Columns(7).Width = 120
    End Sub
    Sub nrocont()
        Dim cmd As SQLite.SQLiteCommand = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "select nrocon from nrocontrol"
        cot = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        Label2.Text = cot
    End Sub
    Private Sub Validar_Numeros(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
        Dim Celda As DataGridViewCell = Me.Dataco.CurrentCell()
        If Celda.ColumnIndex = 3 Or Celda.ColumnIndex = 4 Or Celda.ColumnIndex = 5 Or Celda.ColumnIndex = 7 Then
            If e.KeyChar = ","c Then
                If InStr(Celda.EditedFormattedValue.ToString, ",", CompareMethod.Text) > 0 Then
                    e.Handled = True
                Else
                    e.Handled = False
                End If
            Else
                If Len(Trim(Celda.EditedFormattedValue.ToString)) > 0 Then
                    If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(8) Then
                        e.Handled = False
                    Else
                        e.Handled = True
                    End If
                Else
                    If e.KeyChar = "0"c Then
                        e.Handled = True
                    Else
                        If Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(8) Then
                            e.Handled = False
                        Else
                            e.Handled = True
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
        sumar()
    End Sub
    Private Sub sumar()
        'Calcula subtotal
        For i As Integer = 0 To Dataco.RowCount - 1
            suma += Dataco.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
        Next
        TextBox4.Text = Format(suma, " #,##0.00")
        'calcula iva
        TextBox5.Text = Format(suma * 0.16, " #,##0.00")
        iva = suma * 0.16
        'calcula total
        TextBox6.Text = Format(suma + iva, "#,##0.00")
        total = suma + iva
        total = Nothing
        suma = Nothing
        iva = Nothing
    End Sub
    Sub llenacombo()
        'combobox productos
        Dim query As String = "SELECT descripcion FROM productos"
        Dim dataSet As New DataSet()
        Dim dataAdapter As New SQLiteDataAdapter(query, con)
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "productos")
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables("productos")
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "descripcion"
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
        'combobox marca
        Dim query2 As String = "SELECT descripcion FROM marca"
        Dim dataSet2 As New DataSet()
        Dim dataAdapter2 As New SQLiteDataAdapter(query2, con)
        dataAdapter2.Fill(dataSet2, "marca")
        ComboBox2.DataSource = dataSet2.Tables("marca")
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "descripcion"
        ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = -1
        'combobox presentacion
        Dim query3 As String = "SELECT descripcion FROM presentacion"
        Dim dataSet3 As New DataSet()
        Dim dataAdapter3 As New SQLiteDataAdapter(query3, con)
        dataAdapter3.Fill(dataSet3, "presentacion")
        ComboBox3.DataSource = dataSet3.Tables("presentacion")
        ComboBox3.DisplayMember = "descripcion"
        ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = -1
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox3_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox3.KeyPress
        If Not (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) _
AndAlso (Not e.KeyChar = "," Or TextBox3.Text.Contains(",")) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        'Validar datos
        'verificar que hay tasa
        If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Indique la tasa")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar un producto")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ComboBox2.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar una marca")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ComboBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar una Presentacion")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox9.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar un Precio de Compra en Bolivares")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox7.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar un Precio de Compra en dólares")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox8.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar un Precio de Venta")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox10.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar un a cantidad")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'declaracion de variables
        total = suma + iva
        Dim pro, mar, pre As String
        Dim preb, pred, prev, cant, tota As Double
        pro = ComboBox1.Text
        mar = ComboBox2.Text
        pre = ComboBox3.Text
        preb = TextBox9.Text
        pred = TextBox7.Text
        prev = TextBox8.Text
        cant = TextBox10.Text
        tota = cant * preb
        Dataco.Rows.Add()
        Dim lin As Integer = Dataco.RowCount
        Dataco(0, lin - 1).Value = pro
        Dataco(1, lin - 1).Value = mar
        Dataco(2, lin - 1).Value = pre
        Dataco(3, lin - 1).Value = cant.ToString("N2")
        Dataco(4, lin - 1).Value = preb.ToString("N2")
        Dataco(5, lin - 1).Value = pred.ToString("N2")
        Dataco(6, lin - 1).Value = tota.ToString("N2")
        Dataco(7, lin - 1).Value = prev.ToString("N2")
        sumar()
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox9_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox9.KeyPress
        If Not (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) _
AndAlso (Not e.KeyChar = "," Or TextBox9.Text.Contains(",")) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
            'calcular el precio en dolares
            If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Dim tas, pre, tot As Double
            tas = TextBox3.Text
            'If TextBox9.TextLength = 0 Then
            '    pre = e.KeyChar
            'Else
            pre = TextBox9.Text & e.KeyChar
            'End If

            TextBox7.Text = ""
            tot = pre / tas
            tot = Math.Round(CDbl(tot), 2)
            TextBox7.Text = tot
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox8_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox8.KeyPress
        If Not (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) _
AndAlso (Not e.KeyChar = "," Or TextBox8.Text.Contains(",")) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox7_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox7.KeyPress
        If Not (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) _
AndAlso (Not e.KeyChar = "," Or TextBox7.Text.Contains(",")) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
        If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
            'calcular el precio en dolares
            If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Dim tas, pre, tot As Double
            tas = TextBox3.Text
            pre = TextBox7.Text & e.KeyChar
            TextBox9.Text = ""
            tot = pre * tas
            tot = Math.Round(CDbl(tot), 2)
            TextBox9.Text = tot
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox10_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox10.KeyPress
        If Not (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) OrElse Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) _
AndAlso (Not e.KeyChar = "," Or TextBox10.Text.Contains(",")) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'validacion
        If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Indique la tasa")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar un proveedor")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Debe ingresar un numero de factura")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'llenar compras1
        Dim prov As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim nrof As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim tasa As Double = TextBox3.Text.Replace(",", ".")
        'declaracion de decimales
        Dim valor1 As Double
        Dim valor2 As Double
        Dim valor3 As Double
        valor1 = CDbl(Format(CDbl(TextBox4.Text), "0.00"))
        valor2 = CDbl(Format(CDbl(TextBox5.Text), "0.00"))
        valor3 = CDbl(Format(CDbl(TextBox6.Text), "0.00"))
        'Dim suma1 As Double = CDbl(Val(TextBox4.Text.Replace(",", "."))) '
        'Dim iva1 As Double = CDbl(Val(TextBox5.Text.Replace(",", "."))) '
        'Dim total1 As Double = CDbl(Val(TextBox6.Text.Replace(",", "."))) '
        'suma1 = CDbl(suma1)
        'iva1 = CDbl(iva1)
        'total1 = CDbl(total1)
        Dim fecom As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
        Dim query1 As String = "INSERT INTO compras1 (nrocompra, proveedor, nrofactura, tasa, fechacompra, subtotal, iva, totalc) VALUES ('" & cot & "','" & prov & "','" & nrof & "'," & tasa & "," & fecom & "," & valor1 & ", " & valor2 & ", " & valor3 & ")"
        Dim command1 As New SQLiteCommand(query1, con)
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'llenar compras 2
        For i As Integer = 0 To Dataco.RowCount - 1
            Dim desc As String = Dataco(0, i).Value.ToString
            Dim marc As String = Dataco(1, i).Value.ToString
            Dim pres As String = Dataco(2, i).Value.ToString
            Dim cant As Double = CDbl(Dataco(3, i).Value.ToString)
            Dim prebs As Double = CDbl(Dataco(4, i).Value.ToString)
            Dim predo As Double = CDbl(Dataco(5, i).Value.ToString)
            Dim preve As Double = CDbl(Dataco(7, i).Value.ToString)
            Dim query2 As String = "INSERT INTO compras2 (nrocompra, descripcion, presentacion, marca, cantidad, preciocbs, preciocd, preciov) VALUES ('" & cot & "','" & desc & "','" & pres & "'," & marc & "," & cant & "," & prebs & ", " & predo & ", " & preve & ")"
            Dim command2 As New SQLiteCommand(query2, con)
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        'aumentar el numero de control
        cot = cot + 1
        Dim query As String = "Update nrocontrol Set nrocon =" & cot
        Dim command As New SQLiteCommand(query, con)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Por este tipo de problemas es que yo recomiendo usar Entity Framework, así te olvidas de convertir de tipos y de concatenar querys como string (que de ahí nace tu problema).

Para tu caso, una solución simple sería modificar el `CultureInfo` de tu aplicación y asignar que el punto sea el separador decimal. Adicionalmente veo correcto cambiar además el separador de miles (es decir intercambiarlos), de lo contrario ambos quedarían con un punto

Este código debes ingresarlo al inicio de un aplicación

```
Dim culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone()
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ","
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture
```

Comment: Hola aun asi no me pasa la coma a punto, intenté intercambiarlos en el codigo que me enviaste y tampoco. el problema es netamente cuando pasa por esta linea de codigo Dim query1 As String = "INSERT INTO compras1 (nrocompra, proveedor, nrofactura, tasa, fechacompra, subtotal, iva, totalc) VALUES ('" & cot & "','" & prov & "','" & nrof & "'," & tasa & "," & fecom & "," & valor1 & ", " & valor2 & ", " & valor3 & ")"
las variables van bien, en lo que se ejecuta esa linea de codigo se cambia.